# Listen for NFC while device asleep

Tags: java, android, sdk, sleep, battery

I try to make an app which will catch NFC rfid, start app, and show some data. 
It works well as long as the phone is awake.

Now I find one way - don`t allow the phone to sleep. The app runs constantly with brightness set to 0, and when it detects an NFC signal, brightness goes to 100.

But this is not good for battery. I want to just turn off the screen, but don`t sleep, because I need listen NFC, and wakeup.

Comment: Have you tried using a service?

Comment: No, because I don`t understand how to make listener NFC in service.

Comment: Now i use:
<meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" /> in activity... 
But what I can do in Service ?

Comment: NFC api is not designed to communicate while device is in deep sleep.